# Run asynchronous method in loadInBackground of AsyncTaskLoader

Tags: android, asynchronous, callback, asynctaskloader

I would like to run asynchronous server call using `AsyncTaskLoader`. Method `loadInBackground()` should return the result synchronously. I am returning null and I call `deliverResult()` in callback which is executed on manually created `HandlerThread`. This implementation is sending to UI null at first, then (when async server operation is done) real data. I'm not sure this is good solution.

**How to implement custom `AsyncTaskLoader` properly, where I want to load data by asynchronous server calls (thus using callbacks)?**

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use [join()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join()) `on manually created HandlerThread` (without code it's hard to give a working example)

Comment: Which AsyncTaskLoader method have I call 'join' in?

Comment: I guess loadInBackground, which BTW should be doInBackground

Comment: Great! Working like a charm... Thank you